# mindmap-like layout using visNetwork R package (network visualization using vis.js javascript library)

Tags: r, vis.js

Is it possible to tweak visNetwork's options (e.g. visLayout, visOptions or visPhysics) to obtain a network visualization that resembles a mindmap?

I want to obtain something like this:
[image: Produced using Mindomo]

And here's my reproducible example in `R` using `visNetwork` to draw the same data:

```
nodes <- structure(list(id = 1:22, label = structure(c(14L, 20L, 19L, 
                                                       16L, 12L, 18L, 2L, 17L, 22L, 8L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 21L, 
                                                       15L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("A seemengly impossible mission\n", 
                                                                                       "Another \n", "Detail 1\n", "Detail 2\n", "Detail 3\n", "Detail 4\n", 
                                                                                       "Detail 5\n", "Do you know where is Dover?\n", "Dover Castle\n", 
                                                                                       "Finally, I'm the fifth\n", "I'm alone", "I'm relatively short\n", 
                                                                                       "Let's say there is a third one\n", "Main topic\n", "Operation Dynamo\n", 
                                                                                       "or, I'm even longer and perhaps I need some more space\n", "Running out of imagination\n", 
                                                                                       "Shorter\n", "Some longer text goes here\n", "Thing 1\n", "Thing number 4\n", 
                                                                                       "What can happen?\n"), class = "factor"), shape = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "box")), .Names = c("id", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "label", "shape"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")

edges <- structure(list(from = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
                                 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 21L), to = 2:22, 
                        arrows = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "to", class = "factor")), .Names = c("from", 
                                                                                                                                           "to", "arrows"), row.names = c(NA, 21L), class = "data.frame")
library(visNetwork)
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
    visLayout(randomSeed = 1)
```

This code produces this visualization:

[image]

So you can see that the first figure is much cleaner and easier to read and use. Is it possible to tweak `visNetwork` parameters (vis.js parameters) so as to make the result relatively similar to the first figure here?

Basically it is like to have a central main topic, then the next level topics arranged radially around the main topic, and further levels staked up on each other (kind of a list).

Comment: Maybe have a look at `radialNetwork()` from the [networkD3](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/) package

Answer (score 5):

You can do that passing coordinates to nodes data.frame, and then disable physics.

You can place the nodes where you want and get back coordinates using a shiny app, and then use this in your network, like this for example :

```
mynetwork <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 1) %>%
  visPhysics(enabled = FALSE) # disable physics to move nodes

require(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    mynetwork
  })

  vals <- reactiveValues(coords=NULL)

  output$view <- renderPrint({
    write.table(vals$coords, file = "save_coordinates.csv", sep = ";")
    vals$coords
  })

  observe({
    input$getcoord
    visNetworkProxy("network") %>% visGetPositions()
    vals$coords <- if (!is.null(input$network_positions)) 
      do.call(rbind, input$network_positions)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network", height = "800px"),
  actionButton("getcoord", "View & Save Coordinates"),
  verbatimTextOutput("view")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


# and after, put coordinnates into nodes data.frame and use visNodes(fixed = TRUE) 
# if you want

coord <- read.csv("save_coordinates.csv", sep = ";")
nodes <- cbind(nodes, coord)

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visNodes(fixed = T) %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 1) %>%
  visPhysics(enabled = FALSE)
```

You can also play with `level` and `visHierarchicalLayout` :

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:9, level = c(1,1,2,3,3, 4, 4, 4, 4))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), 
                    to = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))


visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "LR")
```

Comment: thanks!, this is a nice solution. But (there has to be a but) it is a nice solution for a one-timer and one specific network. I was actually looking for something more "automatic", that cleverly arranges the nodes in a mind-map fashion, for any network. The closest I've found is `radialNetwork()` from `networkD3` package, as suggested by @Steven Beaupré , but it is like it arranges all the network radially. I wanted something more like, radially arrangement for the first level, then vertical arrangement for the second level

Comment: Can do that also with `level` and `visHierarchicalLayout`. Put an example in my answer.